# Qt - Convert QDateTime to QJSValue

Tags: qt, type-conversion, qt5, qdatetime

How can I convert a [`QDateTime`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdatetime.html) into a [`QJSValue`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qjsvalue.html)? Converting in the opposite direction is easy: there is `QJSValue::isDate` and `QJSValue::toDateTime`.

Comment: @Amartel toScriptValue works, thank you! If you add your comment as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Qt's help, [QJSEngine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qjsengine.html) is used for converting between QJSValue and object-based types (including Date and RegExp).

Try using `QJSValue QJSEngine::toScriptValue(const T & value)`.